# Generate serialization assembly on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I want to set "Generate serialization assembly" off. But I don't find that option in Project->Properties. Anyone please tell me how to set Generate serialization assembly off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be on the "Build" tag, labelled "Generate serialization assembly":

[image]

Note that it might not appear for all project types; if it doesn't appear, I would *assume* (not always safe...) that it isn't enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am creating an application. When I go to the application properties, I don't see Build Option. I have only Compile option.

Comment: Thank you I got it. It is under Advanced options

Comment: @SuviJoseph in that case, I suspect you're using "Visual Studio Express". If that is the case, you should probably have mentioned it - it is a very different product ;p

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Professional

Comment: @SuviJoseph fair enough; I thought that option only existed in express; TIL